# Pivot table without aggregation in excel

Tags: excel, pivot, office365, pivot-table

Given this table bellow: 
[image]

In Excel,
 when I insert a pivot table, the column 'id' has being calculated to a total sum
**Clearly, it is not needed**

Any thoughts of how can I remove the aggregation from this column alone and keep the same current appearance of the table ( same but without caculating id_1+id2...+idn)

Comment: "ID associated with each name to appear" - Exactly

Comment: But how many IDs are there per name? Only one? So your current Pivot Table is correct apart from the Grand Total row?

Comment: Yes. for simplicity, the Id is a primary key, means that can be one specific id per person but there can be same names for different Id

Comment: You'll need to add your source data to the Data Model and recreate your Pivot Table using Power Pivot. Is this an option for you?

Comment: In this case, yes

Answer (score 1):

Create this **measure**:

```
MyID :=
VAR ThisName =
    MIN( Table1[Name] )
RETURN
    IF(
        HASONEVALUE( Table1[Name] ),
        CALCULATE( MIN( Table1[ID] ), Table1[Name] = ThisName ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

amending table/column names where required.

You can then drag this measure into the Pivot Table Values area.

Comment: Sir, upvoted, since it worked for me like a charm, thanks for this share!